# How to calculate the position of a circle depending on the current time on the curve

Tags: javascript, math, graph, normal-distribution

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1158 696">
   <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:red;stop-opacity:1" />
      <stop offset="50%" style="stop-color:blue;stop-opacity:1" />
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:red;stop-opacity:1" />
    </linearGradient>
   </defs>
   <g><g><g><path fill="none" stroke="url(#grad1)" stroke-miterlimit="50" stroke-width="4" d="M0 212.4c241.4 0 274.174-213.852 579-210 304.826 1.853 345.472 211 581 210"/></g></g></g>
   <g>
      <g opacity=".76">
         <path fill="#011134" d="M.25 214.001c239.653 0 274.65-213.852 580.005-210 305.355 3.853 340.062 210 580.005 210v486H.25v-486z"/>
      </g>
   </g>
   <g transform="translate(0, 198)" >
    <filter id="blurMe">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="2" />
    </filter>
    <circle filter="url(#blurMe)" cx="16" cy="16" r="12" fill="red" />
   </g>
</svg>
```

I've tried to use a formula of [Normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution)

I need to achive a result where the circle moves along the curve depends on the current time for that i need to find a formula which represents the graph described above, but the Gaussian distribution does not give me a desirable graph, the Gaussian distribution gives me next:[image]

Comment: Isn't it the same graph, just flatter?

Comment: Yes, i need a more flatter graph in the top, but i don't know how to make it

Comment: Make deviance greater number. The sigma sign in the formula. (Look at the very first picture on the right side on the Wikipedia page.)